# При установлении backgroundColor для кнопок,цвет выходит за пределы кнопки

Tags: android

Как вы заметили на фото, кнопки прилипают к друг другу. Наверно это из-за площади кнопки. По моему красится не только кнопка, но и площадь вокруг неё ,которая она занимает. Конечно можно увеличить расстояние между кнопками. Но по определенным причинам я не могу это сделать.Как решить проблему? Другими словами,как покрасить только кнопку или как сжать границы кнопки? Надеюсь вы поняли проблему. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Кнопка сама по себе не имеет отступов. Фон для кнопки поумолчанию включает в себя прозрачный отступ. Все что у вас красится в красный и зеленый - и есть кнопка. Добавьте отступы вручную.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете создать в `drawable` свой собственный `background` с прозрачным `stroke` (если вам необходимо соответствовать именно дефолтным кнопкам) для каждого типа кнопки.